# Golang shadowing behavior explanation

Tags: go

In this snippet

```
    list := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    for {
        list := repeat(list)
...

    func repeat(list []string) []string {
...
```

it is clear that `list` variable used as the argument to `repeat()` function is the outer, shadowed list variable.  Now my question is, how would a Go language lawyer explain this behaviour?  At first glance, I thought the declaration of the inner list variable would have preceded the `repeat(list)` expression evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Go is lexically scoped using blocks](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope). In this example:

```
list := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
for {
    list := repeat(list)
```

The second `list` shadows the first within the for block, and doesn't alter the outer `list` variable.

Because the arguments to `repeat` are evaluated before the inner `list` is declared and assigned, `repeat` receives the value from the outer `list`

Answer (score 1):

It's a tough crowd on SO.  The answer I was looking for was essentially that in the statement:

```
list := repeat(list)
```

the inner list variable is not in scope until the end of the statement whereas the outer list variable is in scope.  Here's what the spec has to say:

> Go is lexically scoped using blocks:
>
> The scope of a predeclared identifier is the universe block. The scope
>   of an identifier denoting a constant, type, variable, or function (but
>   not method) declared at top level (outside any function) is the
>   package block. The scope of the package name of an imported package is
>   the file block of the file containing the import declaration. The
>   scope of an identifier denoting a method receiver, function parameter,
>   or result variable is the function body. **The scope of a constant or
>   variable identifier declared inside a function begins at the end of
>   the ConstSpec or VarSpec (ShortVarDecl for short variable
>   declarations) and ends at the end of the innermost containing block.**
>   The scope of a type identifier declared inside a function begins at
>   the identifier in the TypeSpec and ends at the end of the innermost
>   containing block.

The highlighted text is the operational rationale that I missed in the first read.  Mea culpa. :-)